# How to simulate $_FILES image upload with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

After hours and hours of scraping through the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) I've finally decided to ask for assistance as I'm unable to do it myself.

I have 3 URLS, all images that I'd like to download/save to the browser and set it's data into an accessible associative array just as if I were using a HTML form to upload them.

I wasn't able to emulate that properly, best I was able to achieve after reading the docs on [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php), [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)(I thought would've been the solution), [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) was the [**following**](http://codepad.org/Sx1szNze) which wound up being a fail as I hadn't uploaded the file itself like I needed, I had just put some information on an array.

If it's too difficult to understand this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$url = array('url.com/img.jpeg','url.com/img.jpeg','url.com/img.jpeg');

foreach($url as $img){
    // download all 3 images to the browser/local machine temporarily
    // and access them via a variable outside of the foreach scope
    // like below
}

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.24654000 150113339659797a543c31f24.jpg
                    [1] => 0.14997300 1503597010599f11d2249df30.jpg
                    [2] => 0.14997300 1503597010599f11d2249df30.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php143.tmp
                    [1] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php154.tmp
                    [2] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php155.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9425
                    [1] => 55560
                    [2] => 55560
                )
        )
)
```

I'm now taking a look at the tmp_name and it's location, maybe it'd be possible to use `file_get_contents` and `put_file_contents` to the local machine temporarily but how to read the file and get the associative arrays, that part isn't clear at all.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate the `$_FILES` array or are you just trying to move files from one place to another? Like are you trying to test something else  out with this method?

Comment: @Rasclatt, I'm just trying to read the file and get the information into the array, and possibly pass the data from the array to move_uploaded_file later on.

Comment: The thing is that you misunderstand how things works. See you are not moving a file, you are downloading it from another source which means that you need to write (save) it first on your system, and the $_FILES array is used when you UPLOAD a file from a form which is not the case. You can hardcode to add the saved files on it after you saved but I wouldn't recommend that. It makes things messy.

Comment: I see, I think I'll have to change the logic structure to make this work then.